# lot of V/FA: Activity resumed messages in logcat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am getting continuous stream of V/FA: Activity resumed messages in my logcat.

Is it normal?

```
09-20 04:40:00.624 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335457
09-20 04:40:00.644 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335474
09-20 04:40:00.664 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335491 
09-20 04:40:00.684 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335508
09-20 04:40:00.694 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335524
09-20 04:40:00.714 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335541
09-20 04:40:00.724 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335557
09-20 04:40:00.744 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335575
09-20 04:40:00.764 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335591
09-20 04:40:00.784 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335608
09-20 04:40:00.844 8473-8518/com.p.app D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13749K, 51% free 14422K/29136K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
09-20 04:40:00.854 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335680
09-20 04:40:00.854 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335687
09-20 04:40:00.864 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335696
09-20 04:40:00.884 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335712
09-20 04:40:00.904 8473-8508/com.p.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9335729
```

Comment: No, this is not normal.  These informational messages from Firebase Analytics are generated when an activity enters the Resumed state.  Odd that you are not also seeing similar `Activity paused` messages.  Is the activity flow in your app working as you expect?  Are there other indications of excessive activity state changes?  Consider adding debug log-statements to the lifecycle methods of your activities, particularly `onResume()`, to get a better understanding of the issue.